# Cordova and iframe

Tags: android, cordova

I have a sencha-touch application used with cordova.
all work find ( local file, local storage, ajax, json ...)

when i append to one panel a

> html: <iframe src=http://foo.com>

all work find : if foo.com is accessible, the page is shown in the iframe.

But, if foo.com is stopped/inaccessible, i get a alert 'Application error' 
and then the application exit !

Console show:

> CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=Echec de connexion...

cordova 1.9.0

sencha touche 2.0

Android SDK 3.1, to galaxy note Android 4.0.3

Answer (score 3):

Try handling the onReceivedError on your activity.

```
public void onReceivedError( int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
{
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/noConnection.html");
    return;

}
```

Here is a link: http://tech.sarathdr.com/featured/how-to-get-url-not-reached-error-in-anodroid-phonegap

Hope it helps!